# Flatten Lambda expression to access collection property members names

Tags: c#, lambda

Given the following class

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public List<Person> Friends { get; }
}
```

I am looking for a way to get the following string "Friends.Name", when using an Expression>.

Here is the pseudo-code of what I want to do :

```
Expression<Func<Person,string>> exp = x => x.Friends.Name
```

Which won't compile for obvious reasons.

How can I achieve that ? Even if you don't have the code, a general approach would do the trick as I am lacking inspiration on this one.

Thanks

Comment: What does that mean? `get the following string "Friends.Name"`

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev thank you for your interest, this means I want to have the "path" to this property

Comment: And how you want to use that path then?

Comment: I just need the path ; )
I use it for a fancy serialization / deserialization scenario talking to some db

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't get what you want, using this type of expression:

`Expression<Func<Person,string>>`

since `Person` has a collection of `Friends`. Actually, the return type of `Func` doesn't matter here. This will work:

```
    static string GetPath(Expression<Func<Person, object>> expr)
    {
        var selectMethodCall = (MethodCallExpression)expr.Body;
        var collectionProperty = (MemberExpression)selectMethodCall.Arguments[0];
        var collectionItemSelector = (LambdaExpression)selectMethodCall.Arguments[1];
        var collectionItemProperty = (MemberExpression)collectionItemSelector.Body;

        return $"{collectionProperty.Member.Name}.{collectionItemProperty.Member.Name}";
    }
```

Usage:

```
var path = GetPath(_ => _.Friends.Select(f => f.Name)); // Friends.Name
```

But this is a rather simple case, while it seems to me you're doing something like `Include` methods from Entity Framework.
So, if you want to parse more complex expressions, like this:

```
_ => _.Friends.Select(f => f.Children.Select(c => c.Age))
```

you'll need to explore the expression in more generic fashion.

Comment: This is a not a "rather simple case", this is perfect !! Thank you 
Exactly what I needed. I was about to build something way more complex. Thanks for the edit, I see what you mean by complex case know, thanks

Comment: Why is the code doesn't compile ? (it indicates error on `return $"{collectionProperty.Member.Name}.{collectionItemProperty.Member.Name}";` string for some reason

Comment: @Fabjan: this is C# 6 feature (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx). To compile code from VS2013 and below, replace this line to `string.Format` or just string concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the exoression below, you can get the path like this:

```
Expression<Func<Person, string>> exp = x => x.Name; 

var lambdaBody = exp.Body;

if(lambdaBody.NodeType == ExpressionType.MemberAccess)
{
    var memberExpression = lambdaBody as MemberExpression;
    Console.WriteLine(memberExpression.ToString());
}
```

Output:

```
x.Name
```